# MapAt with Replace(All) causing kernel crash

Tags: bugs, replacement, map, crash

**Bug introduced in 10.1 and fixed in 10.2**

---

I wanted to roll a function that works like `/.` but only acts on the very first match it encounters.

```
ReplaceAtFirst =
 Function[{expr, rule}, 
  MapAt[Replace[#, rule] &, expr, FirstPosition[expr, First@rule]]]
```

to demonstrate, how the replacement rule works in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96189/what-does-a-replacement-rule-on-a-symbol-pattern-actually-do).

```
ReplaceAtFirst[x^3 + 2 y, _Symbol -> 1]
(* 1[x^3, 2 y] *)
ReplaceAtFirst[%, _Symbol -> 1]
(* Kernel crashes *)
```

Upon further investigation, it appears, that

```
MapAt[# /. {_Symbol -> 1} &, 1[x], {1}]
```

also crashes the kernel. It appears, that an integer or rational head in the expression `1[x]` leads to a crash. Replacing `1.0[x]` to `1.0[1]` works fine.

Using `ReplacePart` or other replacement functions directly, without `MapAt` also works fine.

Is this a known problem? I am using MMA 10.1 on Win7x64 enterprise.

Comment: None of your examples crash for me with mma v10.2.0 (OSX 10.9.5).

Comment: Yes, it crashes with 10.1, but not with 10.0 or 10.2.  Tested on OS X.

Comment: @Szabolcs It works on MMA 8.0 and MMA 10.2 under Win7x64. Looks like a bug introduced somewhere in between and resolved in 10.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Bug introduced in 10.1 and fixed in 10.2**

From the comments of @Szabolcs and @SquareOne:

Works under OS X in 10.0 and 10.2, but not in 10.1.

From my observations:

Works under Win7x64 in 8.0 and 10.2, but not 10.1.